# How to apply a local function to specific columns of a data frame in a function in python?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to define a function in python in which negative values in a data frame in specific columns are capped to zero. So I defined a function that gets x as input and if it is negative it caps it to zero (cap0) and then applies this function to specific columns. However, when I write my function in python, it keeps running (llike there is no closure for my function). Appreciate it if you can help me.

P.S. I am pretty new to python

```
def captozero(df, cap_vars):
   def cap0(x):
       x_out = x.copy()
       x_out = np.where(x_out < 0, 0, x)
       return x_out
   df_out = df.copy()
   df_out = df_out.apply(lambda x: cap0(x) if x.name in [cap_vars] else x)
   return df_out
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a numpy function that compare the results and take the maximum.
In your case,

```
for i in cap_vars:
    df[i] = np.maximum(df[i], 0)
```

or you can use the np.where for each column

```
for i in cap_vars:
    df[i] = np.where(df[i] < 0, 0, df[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `DataFrame.clip` that you can use for this purpose:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[-1,2,4],'col2':[2,-3,5], 'col3':[1,2,3]})
print(df, '\n')

df.update(df[['col1', 'col2']].clip(0))

print(df)
```

producing the following output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    -1     2     1
1     2    -3     2
2     4     5     3 

   col1  col2  col3
0     0     2     1
1     2     0     2
2     4     5     3
```

note the use of the update function to overwrite the columns in the dataframe with the newly clipped versions